# How to add the title on the top and the value in bottom using Barchart using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Last two days, I am trying to perform the chart same as below in the image using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I almost able to execute exactly same but I have few points that do not know how to do it. As below

1. In a chart, how to show the title on the top the chart i.e sun, mon,. 
   I had tried but it shows the vertical line and does only support the float value. I am trying usingBarchart.
2. The second point is how to show the value in a bottom of the bar. I try the property but it shows the value above the bar or inside the bar but could not see how to set the position at the bottom as you see in chart image.

Thanks, if someone could guide me in these two points.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this to set the values below the chart ? xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)

Comment: I do not want to set the xAxis value (i.e sun, mon etc.) at a bottom. I know this property. Actually, I want to show the bar value at bottom of the bar that you can see into the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is that answer of the point first, How to set/show the custom title over the bar chart?

For that, we can use the **setValueFormatter(..)** method by override the two method **getFormattedValue** and **getDecimalDigits()**. Inside the 
get formatted value we return String of title. Instead of decimal value.
Becuase in my case has to show the string value. See below the complete code snippet.

```
private String[] weeksName = {"Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon","Today"};

mDashBoardBinding.progressSection.barView.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return weeksName[(int) value];
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

For Next point, I wondering how to align the value of the bar in bottom direction. I will update it once i found the solution.

Thanks,
Bhavdip

Answer (score 0):

For showing the values at the bottom of the bar, I did this:

XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);

Hide the values ( set them as "")

BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(yVals, "Legend");

```
    set.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
                return "";
        }
    });
```

And actually set the formatted values on the labels.

Hope it helps

[See image here - Show values at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0GTm.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Will try after that update you.